# Function not returning expected value

Tags: c, function

I've been practicing C for quite a few weeks now and I'm tryin to figure out what I might have done wrong in my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct accounts{
    char unList[32];
    int pinList;
    float amtList;

}account;

int isValid(char inputUN[], account acount[]);
void initialize(account acount[], char unList[][10], int pinList[], float amtList[], int size);





int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int size = 10;

    account newAccs[size];
    char unList[][10] = {"franklin", "woods", "phillips", "gomez", "burns", "porter", "griffin", "spencer", "hanson", "johnson"};


    char inputUN[32];
    int index;

    initialize(newAccs, unList, pinList, amtList, size);

    printf("Enter Username: ");
    scanf("%s", inputUN);




    index = isValid(inputUN, newAccs);
    printf("%d\n", index);


return 0;   
}

void initialize(account acount[], char unList[][10], int pinList[], float amtList[], int size){
    int index;

    for(index = 0; index < size; index++){
        strcpy(acount[index].unList, unList[index]);
        acount[index].pinList = pinList[index];
        acount[index].amtList = amtList[index];
    }
}



int isValid(char inputUN[], account acount[] ){

    int index;
    int y;

    for(index = 0; index < 10; index++){
        if (strcmp(acount[index].unList, inputUN ) == 0){
            y = index;
        }else{
            y= -1;

        }

    }

return y;
}
```

What I am really trying to do in this program is that the program is asking for a username input and Pin then it checks if both are in the structure and then it shows some amount, but i have ommitted the rest of the code since my problem is in the `isValid()` function...

```
 int isValid(char inputUN[], account acount[] ){

    int index;
    int y;

    for(index = 0; index < 10; index++){
        if (strcmp(acount[index].unList, inputUN ) == 0){
            y = index;
        }else{
            y= -1;

        }

    }

return y;
}
```

in this function it is supposed return the index of the element if the username is in the structure, else it returns `-1`. It works well if I placed comments in the `else if` statement. But if not, it always returns `-1` even if I have input a correct element.

What might I have done wrong?

P.S. Sorry If my question was too long, I'm quite new to Stacks Overflow

Comment: Where is your `initialize` function?

Comment: oh sorry.. i will add it...

Comment: have you tried to put a breakpoint to y=index to see if it ever got assigned a value? Also after being assigned you should break the loop or next one can reassign y to -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you find the match you should break out of the `for` loop by adding a `break;` statement. Otherwise unless it matches the last option it will return -1. Like this:

```
int isValid(char inputUN[], account acount[] ){

int index;
int y;

for(index = 0; index < 10; index++){
    if (strcmp(acount[index].unList, inputUN ) == 0){
        y = index;
        break;
    }else{
        y= -1;

    }

}

return y;
}
```

or You can initialize `y` to `-1` and test for it, like this:

```
int isValid(char inputUN[], account acount[] ){

int index;
int y = -1;

for(index = 0; index < 10 && y == -1; index++){
    if (strcmp(acount[index].unList, inputUN ) == 0){
        y = index;
    }else{
        y= -1;

    }

}

return y;
}
```

Comment: Your solution still doesn't work because it has the else clause still

Comment: @ChrisTurner it's definitely redundant, but should not have any negative effect it you break out before the next iteration.

Comment: Sorry - hadn't spotted you'd altered the for exit condition. It's just not as clearly readable as the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you never exited the loop when you found the matching record.

```
int isValid(char inputUN[], account acount[] ){

    int index;

    for(index = 0; index < 10; index++){
        if (strcmp(acount[index].unList, inputUN ) == 0){
            return index; // return directly
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```